# Regarding Android libraries and GUI elements

Tags: java, android, user-interface, libraries

I currently have developed an app with some GUI and network operations, but I need to make it more of a library.

I know that there is a "is library" option under Properties/Android. But the question is: how to move the GUI elements out of the project to a different app, so that the library/project will have only java code; any suggestion ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> libraries should consist of only Java files

No, you can use your project as android library which can look like regular android project. You can just set flag "is library" and add this library to your main project.

Comment: I understood that part, but the question was more of how to move the GUI elements out of the project to a different app, so that the library/project will have only java; any suggestion ?

Comment: 0. You want use GUI from you library project in the main project? 1. GUI - what do you mean by this word?

Comment: GUI in the sense all the XML files which have the graphical user interface components, i want to move that out to a different application and make the library consist of Java code.

Comment: If you need move you xml layouts - you can just copy/paste them into your project(in proper folders like res/layout etc). And then just package your class files into jar and add this jar to your project (put iar into libs folder).

Comment: Yes, I did that but I am getting a whole bunch of errors as my java code consists of many async tasks which populate my XML /GUI elements.